# how to clear JDateChooser field?

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I am using a JDateChooser as a component in a JForm. I have setup a JButton, which resets all of the fields on this form to blank. I do not have issues with the actionListener, or the method for clearing, but instead am unsure how to clear the JDateChooser component.

More specifically I am wondering how to clear the Date from the JTextField component of the date chooser, such that it is blank.

Furthermore, I would like to set this field to the current date after it is cleared.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to clear the JDateChooser field:

```
JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
dateChooser.setCalendar(null);
```

This code will set the field to `null`.

To set the date to today you can use for example:

```
dateChooser.setDate(new Date())
```

Comment: dateChooser.setCalendar(null); null pointer exception

Answer (score 1):

If dateChooser is your instanceof JDateChooser:

```
dateChooser.setDate(new Date());
```

Edit:
I'm not sure what you meen by "set todays date". I assumed you meant set the date in the JDateChooser to todays date (that's what my code does). If it is not what you want, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
((JTextField)dateChooser.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).setText("");
dateChooser.setDate(new Date());
```