# Issue in JDateChooser in jcalendar-1.2.2

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar

Can I have empty date in datechooser with `jcalendar-1.2.2`? I can not use `datechooser.setCalendar(null)`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11719917/230513), because the `setCalendar()` method is not available in `jcalendar-1.2.2`.

Comment: Why can't you update?

Comment: Because the project I have created is a plugin and the parent project is already using jcalendar-1.2.2 jar If I have to update, then it requires some amount of work to update in many places. Is it possible to work this version?

Comment: Maybe someone who's still using the old version can answer.