# Jdatechooser content

Tags: java, swing, getdate, jcalendar

im trying to get de date from a a jdatechooser, then convert it to a string, but when I try to do this `this.fechaTxt.setText("");` it doesnot let me

```
        String fecha1 = this.fechaTxt.getDate().toString();

        Viaje viaje = new Viaje();

        viaje.setFecha(fecha1);


        try {
            this.ingresarViaje(viaje);

            this.fechaTxt.setText("");

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Viaje Ingresado");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR" + e.getMessage());

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719917/how-to-clear-jdatechooser-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by getting the actual date from the `JDateChooser`...

```
Date date = fechaText.getDate();
```

Then you could use [`DateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) or a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format as a `String`

Just remember, unless you need to display the date for some reason, you really shouldn't convert it to a `String`, but instead leave it as a `Date` object